# Why local variable still showing warning though value is used in the method?

Tags: java, variables, compiler-warnings

```
 boolean flag = false;
 String s1= "Bharath";
 String s2 = null;
 flag = s1.equals(s2);
```

I have initialised flag with value as `false` while declaration and I've used it in the same method but it is still showing warning. What is the reason for that?

Comment: paste the code here rather than image or link.

Comment: You have not **read** the variable. You're only assigning to it.

Comment: It means it's assigned but never used . You have to use just print `(System.out.println(flag);)`it will go

Comment: don't set it with a default value that will be overridden anyway. declare and set it as: boolean flag = s1.equals(s2); after that, use the value, either as a param to another method, in a condition, or print it, ...

Comment: @soorapadman , how come addition of code to question does not make the question readable?

Comment: You have not read the variable, and you haven't read the warning message that says so either. Don't post pictures of text here. Post the text. It is a complete waste of your time and our bandwidth.

Comment: I got the point. Thank you all for your answers.

Answer (score 2):

you have only declared the variable flag but have not used or read it anywhere that's why its showing warning. Just put `System.out.println(flag);` it will go away.

Answer (score 0):

As it was already said in the comments. You have initialized variable `flag` with value `false` which was never read and then overridden with `s1.equals(s2)`. So the first assignment was unneccessary.

Workaround: Assign values to variables when needed. Don't assign default values to variables if you don't have to.

Example1:

```
boolean flag;
String s1 = "Bharath";
String s2 = null;
flag = s1.equals(s2);
```

Example2:

```
String s1 = "Bharath";
String s2 = null;
boolean flag = s1.equals(s2);
```

If variables have "fixed" values and are not indented to change, you could also use the `final` keyword.

```
final boolean flag;
String s1 = "Bharath";
String s2 = null;

// flag will never change
flag = s1.equals(s2);
// not allowed, because final
// flag = true;
```